# How to register F12 as a hotkey

Tags: windows, hotkeys, registerhotkey

Per [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309.aspx):

> The <kbd>F12</kbd> key is reserved for use by the debugger at all times, so it
>   should not be registered as a hot key. Even when you are not debugging
>   an application, <kbd>F12</kbd> is reserved in case a kernel-mode debugger or a
>   just-in-time debugger is resident.

However, somehow there is a workaround as AutoHotkey works with <kbd>F12</kbd>. Does anybody have any idea how?

Comment: Why do you assume that AHK uses hotkeys?  It is much more likely to use a hook.

Comment: Agreed, especially after finding that to be my own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure how AutoHotkey does it after looking at the source for a short bit. However, I began to think about things differently. Instead of trying to use `RegisterHotKey` as I have done for all other keys, I decided to try listening to ALL keys. And, VOILA, using [a low level keyboard hook from Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx), I am now able to at least see the <kbd>F12</kbd>. I'll use RegisterHotKey for everything else, but will listen for <kbd>F12</kbd> separately via this hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can just map it to something else for example:`F12::Send ^c`
Edit: using a third party application like AutoHotKey.

Comment: Sorry I miss read the question, AutoHotKey is a third party application that allows you to write scripts for hotkeys, remapping etc.